# Using associatedtype in a delegate protocol for a generic type

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, associated-types

I have a `Game` class. I made it generic because I was need to support different types of boards. Now I just want to add a classical iOS-style delegate with a method which will take a game and a new points value as parameters. How to achieve this in the Swift `associatedtype` way? I really confused that I can't impelemnt such simple logic.

```
protocol GamePointsDelegate {
    associatedtype B: Board
    func game(_ game: Game<B>, didSetPoints points: Int)
}

class Game<B: Board> {
    let board: Board

    var points = 0 {
        // Compiler Error
        // Member 'game' cannot be used on value of protocol type 'GamePointsDelegate'; use a generic constraint instead
        didSet { pointsDelegate?.game(self, didSetPoints: points) }
    }

    // Compiler Error
    // Protocol 'GamePointsDelegate' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
    var pointsDelegate: GamePointsDelegate?
}
```

Comment: Would it be feasible to remove the associated type and just use a generic function `game`?

Comment: You can't have a `var pointsDelegate` of type `GamePointsDelegate`, because `GamePointsDelegate` isn't a type. It's like a template for a type, which produces a new type for every possible value of `B`.

Comment: @Alexander, I understand. But I already have `B` in `Game` and I want to use that somehow.

Comment: @kelin  If you must use an associated type in `GamePointsDelegate`, then `Game` needs a new generic parameter, call it `Delegate`, of type `GamePointsDelegate` where `Self.Delegate.B` == `Self.B`.

Comment: @Alexander, thanks for explanation. I would prefer generic function because it much simpler.

Comment: @kelin Yes, it's the preferable choice. I'm merely pointing out what would be necessary to make this associated type approach work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could remove the associated type requirement from your protocol and use a generic function `game` instead:

```
protocol GamePointsDelegate {
    func game<B>(_ game: Game<B>, didSetPoints points: Int)
}
```

So you can use the code of your `Game` class as it is but the downside is that the class which conforms to the protocol has to handle all `Board`s.

Comment: This gives me a warning: "Redundant conformance constraint 'B': 'Board'". But if I remove `Board` from generic declaration everything compiles. Thanks!